# Jquery Sticky Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, tabs

I have searched through this entire site but i couldn't find what i was looking for.

I am using Jquery UI tabs and i try to keep the page on the selected tabs when the page is refreshed.

This is what i got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cookieName = 'stickyTab';

 $('#tabs').tabs({
  selected: ($.cookies.get(cookieName) || 0),
  select: function(e, ui){
   $.cookies.set(cookieName, ui.index);
  }
 });
});
```

It works fine in Safari but it doesnt work in IE, which is the problem.
Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

What's your subdomain like? [IE will reject cookies from non-valid ones](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> [domain names] must start with a letter, end with a letter or digit,
>   and have as interior characters only
>   letters, digits, and hyphen.

If you have something like an underscore in the subdomain (`my_test.blah.com`), it won't work on IE.

Comment: well it is a subdomain, but nothing special i guess.

http://event.dalenberg.nl/boten/klassieke-schepen/20-personen-johanna/

it is made with wordpress (it is in dutch though)